# "Real" Object References in Distributed Cache?

Tags: distributed-cache

I'm personally committed to .net distributed caching solutions, but I think this question is interesting across all platforms.

Is there a distributed caching solution (or generic strategy) that allows to both store objects in the cache while maintaining the integrity of the references between them?

To exemplify - Suppose I have an object `Foo foo` that references an object `Bar bar` and also and object `Foo foo2` that references that same `Bar bar`. If I load `foo` to the cache, a copy of `bar` is stored along with it. If I also load `foo2` to the cache, a separate copy of `bar` is stored along with that. If I change `foo.bar` in the cache, the change does not impact `foo2.bar` :(

Is there an existing distributed cache solution that will enable me to load `foo`, `foo2` and `bar` into the cache while maintaining the `foo.bar` `foo2.bar` references?

Answer (score 3):

**First and foremost**

I do not know of any distributed system, and I do not pretend to build one. This post explains how you can simulate this behavior with .NET and C# using the IObjectReference interface with serializable objects.

**Now, lets go on with the show**

I do not know of such a distributed system, but you can somewhat easily achive this with .NET using the [IObjectReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iobjectreference.aspx) interface. Your implementation of [ISerializable.GetObjectData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.getobjectdata.aspx) would need to call [SerializationInfo.SetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfo.settype.aspx) to point out a proxy class that implements IObjectReference, and would be able (with help from data provided by your GetObjectData method) to get a reference to the real object that should be used.

Example code:

```
[Serializable]
internal sealed class SerializationProxy<TOwner, TKey> : ISerializable, IObjectReference {
    private const string KeyName = "Key";
    private const string InstantiatorName = "Instantiator";
    private static readonly Type thisType = typeof(SerializationProxy<TOwner, TKey>);
    private static readonly Type keyType = typeof(TKey);

    private static readonly Type instantiatorType = typeof(Func<TKey, TOwner>);
    private readonly Func<TKey, TOwner> _instantiator;
    private readonly TKey _key;

    private SerializationProxy() {
    }

    private SerializationProxy(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
        if (info == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("info");

        _key = (TKey)info.GetValue(KeyName, keyType);
        _instantiator = (Func<TKey, TOwner>)info.GetValue(InstantiatorName, instantiatorType);
    }

    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
        throw new NotSupportedException("This type should never be serialized.");
    }

    object IObjectReference.GetRealObject(StreamingContext context) {
        return _instantiator(_key);
    }

    internal static void PrepareSerialization(SerializationInfo info, TKey key, Func<TKey, TOwner> instantiator) {
        if (info == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("info");
        if (instantiator == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("instantiator");

        info.SetType(thisType);
        info.AddValue(KeyName, key, keyType);
        info.AddValue(InstantiatorName, instantiator, instantiatorType);
    }
}
```

This code would be called with SerializationProxy.PrepareSerialization(info, myKey, myKey => LoadedInstances.GetById(myKey)) from your GetObjectData method, and your LoadedInstances.GetById should return the instance from a Dictionary<TKey, WeakReference> or load it from cache/database if it isnt already loaded.

EDIT:

I've wrote some example code to show what I mean.

```
public static class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        // Create an item and serialize it.
        // Pretend that the bytes are stored in some magical
        // domain where everyone lives happily ever after.
        var item = new Item { Name = "Bleh" };
        var bytes = Serialize(item);

        {
            // Deserialize those bytes back into the cruel world.
            var loadedItem1 = Deserialize<Item>(bytes);
            var loadedItem2 = Deserialize<Item>(bytes);

            // This should work since we've deserialized identical
            // data twice.
            Debug.Assert(loadedItem1.Id == loadedItem2.Id);
            Debug.Assert(loadedItem1.Name == loadedItem2.Name);

            // Notice that both variables refer to the same object.
            Debug.Assert(ReferenceEquals(loadedItem1, loadedItem2));

            loadedItem1.Name = "Bluh";
            Debug.Assert(loadedItem1.Name == loadedItem2.Name);
        }

        {
            // Deserialize those bytes back into the cruel world. (Once again.)
            var loadedItem1 = Deserialize<Item>(bytes);

            // Notice that we got the same item that we messed
            // around with earlier.
            Debug.Assert(loadedItem1.Name == "Bluh");

            // Once again, force the peaceful object to hide its
            // identity, and take on a fake name.
            loadedItem1.Name = "Blargh";

            var loadedItem2 = Deserialize<Item>(bytes);
            Debug.Assert(loadedItem1.Name == loadedItem2.Name);
        }
    }

    #region Serialization helpers
    private static readonly IFormatter _formatter
        = new BinaryFormatter();

    public static byte[] Serialize(ISerializable item) {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
            _formatter.Serialize(stream, item);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(Byte[] bytes) {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes)) {
            return (T)_formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}

// Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious interface.
public interface IDomainObject {
    Guid Id { get; }
}

// Holds all loaded instances using weak references, allowing
// the almighty garbage collector to grab our stuff at any time.
// I have no real data to lend on here, but I _presume_ that this
// wont be to overly evil since we use weak references.
public static class LoadedInstances<T>
    where T : class, IDomainObject {

    private static readonly Dictionary<Guid, WeakReference> _items
        = new Dictionary<Guid, WeakReference>();

    public static void Set(T item) {
        var itemId = item.Id;
        if (_items.ContainsKey(itemId))
            _items.Remove(itemId);

        _items.Add(itemId, new WeakReference(item));
    }

    public static T Get(Guid id) {
        if (_items.ContainsKey(id)) {
            var itemRef = _items[id];
            return (T)itemRef.Target;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

[DebuggerDisplay("{Id} {Name}")]
[Serializable]
public class Item : IDomainObject, ISerializable {
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    // This constructor can be avoided if you have a 
    // static Create method that creates and saves new items.
    public Item() {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        LoadedInstances<Item>.Set(this);
    }

    #region ISerializable Members
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
        // We're calling SerializationProxy to call GetById(this.Id)
        // when we should be deserialized. Notice that we have no
        // deserialization constructor. Fxcop will hate us for that.
        SerializationProxy<Item, Guid>.PrepareSerialization(info, Id, GetById);
    }
    #endregion

    public static Item GetById(Guid id) {
        var alreadyLoaded = LoadedInstances<Item>.Get(id);
        if (alreadyLoaded != null)
            return alreadyLoaded;

        // TODO: Load from storage container (database, cache).
        // TODO: The item we load should be passed to LoadedInstances<Item>.Set
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Simon, thank you for the elaborate reply. I'm afraid it went a bit over my head. Could you explain how the serialization proxy relates to the distributed cache where I intend to store the objects?