# How to share same object instance (singleton) between processes in C#?

Tags: c#, singleton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to share objects across processes in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763821/how-to-share-objects-across-processes-in-net)

I can do this for a single process (single .exe) but how can I do it between processes?

Comment: I think you are looking for - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763821/how-to-share-objects-across-processes-in-net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763821/how-to-share-objects-across-processes-in-net)

Comment: I think you are looking for - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763821/how-to-share-objects-across-processes-in-net

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via [remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(VS.71).aspx). You class needs to inherit from [MarshalByRefObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx), which will give your clients a proxy to the real object.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use some sort of [distributed hash table](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=distributed+hash+table) or caching mechanism.

Try to avoid things like remoting if you can, because calls to a remote object can get expensive and start to really hurt performance.  If you do go with .net remoting, then carefully consider the interface of the remote object.  You should be passing coarse grained data across the process boundry, so avoid chatty interfaces with lots of calls with little bits of data.

What are the requirements of the class that you want to act as a singleton?  There might be a totally different way of looking at it.  Currently the thinking is that singletons are undesirable because they are difficult to unit test reliably, so avoiding the singleton concept could be the direction to take.

Answer (score 0):

using .Net remoting
(see answers above or by this url: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @BryanCrosby thank you for notes, just place correct link there