# C# Object Sharing (IPC)

Tags: c#, wcf, ipc

Question of design here. I have a process (which I do not create) which will load a C# DLL (which I create) and pass it an Object.  I want a second process (which I also create) to have full access to this Object such that mutating it from my second process will be as if I had mutated it directly from my C# DLL.

Is WCF the answer to this? Is there another form of inter-process communication I should look into?

Comment: if you know the process id of the first process, you could require it (`TcpListener`) to communicate over an "agreed" port which the second process could connect to when it needs to (`TcpClient`). Would that work?

Comment: Possible duplicate to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763821/how-to-share-objects-across-processes-in-net

Comment: @Pat TCP solution (as you describe it) seems like it would result it would result in modifying a COPY.....

Comment: @Matt Yeah maybe, I didn't see that. Anyone else think this would work for my specific use case? Seems like it...